# Mongoid Taking .8 seconds to load

Tags: mongoid

I noticed that my app was pretty slow for guard to rerun the current test i was working on. I quickly profiled it and found that Mongoid was taking .4 to .5 seconds to require.

Is that normal for Mongoid? I'm using Mongoid 4.0.0 and Ruby 2.1.2

Anyway to speed that up?